# PayPal Express Checkout useraction and paymenttype parameters in SDK

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I'm using both the merchant .net SDK and the payflow .net sdk.

The documentation talks about being able to set a "useraction" property to "commit".  I can't figure out how to set that property in either of the SDKs.

Also...

The payflow SDK allows me to set PaymentType to "instantonly".

```
ECSetRequest setRequest = new ECSetRequest();
setRequest.PaymentType = "instantonly";
```

The merchant SDK allows me to do the following.

```
PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
paymentDetails.AllowedPaymentMethod = AllowedPaymentMethodType.INSTANTPAYMENTONLY;
```

Hopefully these two are equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach the useraction in the URL you are redirecting to.. eg:

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=<TOKEN>&useraction=commit`

The two PaymentTypes you have listed are the same according to the API.

Also, based on [this sample code](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Samples/PayPalAPISample/APICalls/SetExpressCheckout.aspx.cs) you should be able to add the `useraction=commit` with the MerchantSDK.

Line 420 shows:

```
CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_redirectURL", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL"].ToString()
  + "_express-checkout&token=" + setECResponse.Token);
```

and can be changed to:

```
CurrContext.Items.Add("Response_redirectURL", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL"].ToString()
  + "_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=" + setECResponse.Token);
```

Comment: I don't think its that easy.  The SDKs only have you specify the protocol and domain.  For the merchant API https://www.sandbox.paypal.com, and the payflow API pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com.  There's no cgi-bin/webscr etc.

Comment: Can you post the part of your code where it redirects the user to PayPal?

Comment: Dope, my bad.  Yes I can use "useraction=commit" at the point in the code that redirects to paypal.  Thanks