# Paypal Express Checkout - Change Continue button to PAY

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, sdk

I'm currently integrating the Paypal Express Checkout gateway in one of my website.
I'm using the .NET Paypal SDK (NUGET/Visual Studio 2013). I read Paypal's documentation and followed their guidelines and examples. I was able to get it working (after a little trial and error). But, the thing is, i'm not sure that my flow of operation is optimal. Let me explain the flow:

1) Customer logs in to the website

2) Customer chooses a Monthly plan to advertise on our website and click the paypal button (API CALL: SetExpressCheckout).

3) Customer is redirected to Paypal login page. Enter credentials and logs in.

4) Customer (still on Paypal page) reviews buying informations and clicks 'Continue' button (or Cancel link)

5) Customer is redirected to a Confirmation/Success Callback page on my website (API CALL on pageLoad event: GetExpressCheckoutDetails).

6) Customer (still in Confirmation Callback page) clicks an 'Accept transaction' button (or a cancel button). (API CALL: DoExpressCheckout)

7) Payment is processed and Paypal sends last payment details (status Completed, Pending, etc) to my Instant Payment Notification Callback URL on my website.

---

Now, the thing is, i've recently bought a digital album on Bandcamp and their flow was different at one part and more concise, and well, more 'express' than mine:

1) Customer clicks Name you price link. A modal opens.

2) Customer enters the amount and clicks the 'Checkout now' button.

3) Customer is redirected to Paypal login page. Enter credentials and logs in.

4) Customer (still on Paypal page) reviews buying informations and clicks 'PAY' button (or Cancel link)

5) Customer is redirected to a Confirmation/Success Callback page Bandcamp website. Payment is already processed and nothing more is asked of the customer.

**So the question is how do change the 'Continue' button on Paypal to a 'Pay' button?** 
I can't seem to find my way on Google to answer this question, nor do i see this flow in my documentation?...

Note that these are both digital goods and no shipping is required.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When redirecting to PayPal add `useraction=commit` to the URL:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=<TOKEN>
```

or

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=<TOKEN>
```

A similar question was asked just a few days ago: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523761/paypal-express-checkout-useraction-and-paymenttype-parameters-in-sdk/) If you want a more detailed answer you are going to have to post the part of your code where you redirect users to PayPal.

Comment: Thank you! I will check the other post and re-test everything with this new parameter

Comment: Just remember that it's not a parameter that you set in expresscheckout - it is part of the url when you redirect.

Comment: Another question: Since this changes the flow completely, how will paypal notify me with their Instant Payment Notification to my callback URL if it was set in the API Call DoExpressCheckout, which will not be called anymore? I think you can set this URL in the business account, but i'm not sure? am i right?

Comment: This shouldn't change what happens with IPN, and you still need to call DoExpressCheckout when they get back to your website. All this change does is change **Continue** to **Pay** so that your customer knows they do not need to click anything on your website when they get back.

Comment: Hmm, ok... So, you mean that when the customer is redirected to my Success Callback, after clicking 'PAY' on paypal, on my pageLoad event, i need to call GetExpressCheckoutDetails to get PayerID and Token and then Call DoExpressCheckout to process the payment (still on pageLoad). This way, the user will not have to click anything else

Comment: You got it. Then you can display receipt/whatever.

Comment: Alright!! I'm going to test this right now. Thanks for your patience, hehe

Comment: Everything is working perfectly as it should. The button is now Pay on the paypal page and i received my Instant Payment Notification after calling DoExpressCheckout in my pageLoad event. Also, in my case, i realized that the API call GetExpressCheckoutDetails was optional and i was not obligated to use it. Thank you for you help Aaron! Much appreciated

Comment: For more info, see "Eliminating Your Order Review Page" on page 17 in this document:

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pfp_expresscheckout_pp.pdf